# vba code for Find the date

Tags: vba, excel, date

Sheet 1:- I mentioned the date in Range A1 with dd-mmm format (i.e., 01-Sep)

Sheet 2:- I updated all the date (from Jan to Dec) with same format (dd-mmm)

But I'm unable to find (select the cell) the date.
I wrote as below:

```
Sub UpdateToday()
Dim x As String
Dim Cell As Range
x = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
Range("C10:NC10").Select'All 360 days
Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "dd-mmm"
Set Cell = Selection.Find(What:=x, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=True).Activate
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Are the cells in `Sheet2` held as `Text` or are they dates too?

Comment: They are dates... I formatted it as dd-mmm

Comment: Also I need if in sheet1 I use =today() instead of full date to update today's value

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.  Do you mean `A1` will contain the formula `=TODAY()`?  If so, then this will not impact my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues:

1. Unless you think it's absolutely necessary, I would remove the notion of searching on the format.  Adding the format into the search is only complicating it. I would remove the formatting criteria and simply change the `LookIn` parameter to the `Find` method from `xlValues` to be `xlFormulas` so that the formatting does not matter at all.
2. You need to define `x` as `Date` to hold the true value as it is stored in all of the cells.
3. Your code will only find the first cell with the same date and there could be many.  Not sure if this was your intention.
4. You can't `Activate` at the same time as assigning the `Cell` variable. You need to do this in two steps.

I would update your code to look like this:-

```
Sub UpdateToday()

  Dim x As Date
  Dim Cell As Range
  x = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
  Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
  Range("N10:NC10").Select 'All 360 days
  Set Cell = Selection.Find(What:=x, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
  If Not Cell Is Nothing Then
    Cell.Activate
  End If

  Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Glad to help.  If it solved your problem, please considering marking it as accepted and upvoting it.

Comment: This StackOverflow help article will tell you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :)